# php Parsing HTML getting PRE text and saving it to file

Tags: php, parsing

I'm parsing an html file, and getting contents of a pre tag then saving it to a text file.

however when i open the text file in sublime, or other text editors the formmating is gone, 
My question: how can i save the text in its original state inside the txt file.

the contents of the pre are below this:

```
          x4                                          x4
|---------------------|-|-------------------|--------------------|
|---------------------|-|-------------------|--------------------|
|----------2-0-0------|-|-------------------|--------------------|
|----------------1-0-0|-|-------------------|--------------------|
|3-0-1-3-0------------|0|1-3-1-3-1-3-1-0----|1-3-1-3-1-3-1-0---0-|


           x4                                    x4
|------------------------|-------------|-------------------|
|------------------------|-------------|-------------------|
|------------------------|-------------|-------------------|
|------------------------|-------------|0--0033------------|
|1-3-1-3-1-3-1-0--0000--0|1-3-1-3-1-3-1|--------333~-335-0-|


            x4                      x4
|------------------------|---------------------|-|-------------|
|------------------------|---------------------|-|-------------|
|------------------------|----------2-0-0------|-|-------------|
|------------------------|----------------1-0-0|-|-------------|
|0--0000--0-1-3-1-3-1-3-1|3-0-1-3-0------------|0|1-3-1-3-1-3-1|
```

my code:

```
<?php
     // example of how to use basic selector to retrieve HTML contents
     include('simple_html_dom.php');

     // get DOM from URL or file
     $html = file_get_html('http://metaltabs.com/tab/10464/index.html');

     foreach($html->find('title') as $e)
       echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
       $my_file = fopen("textfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");


    foreach($html->find('pre') as $e)
       echo nl2br($e->innertext) . '<br>';
       $txt = $e->innertext;
       fwrite($my_file, $txt);
       fclose($my_file);
?>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the original of the relevant part of the file you're parsing?

Comment: this is a link to an original file: http://metaltabs.com/tab/4086/index.html im trying to save the contents of the PRE tag

Comment: you have to show your code.

Comment: Updated the question with code, thanks.

Comment: Could you show what the file looks like once you open it with a text editor?

Answer (score 1):

The problems with your parsing results are:

1. Line breaks are not preserved;
2. HTML entities are preserved.

To resolve line break issue you have to use `->load()` instead of `file_get_html`:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$data = file_get_contents( 'http://metaltabs.com/tab/10464/index.html' );

$html->load( $data , True, False );
/*                   └─┬┘  └─┬─┘
       Optional parameter  Optional parameter
                lowercase  Strip \r\n
*/
```

To resolve entities issue you can use php function ``:

```
$txt = html_entity_decode( $e->innertext );
```

The result is something like this:

```
Tuning E A D G B E

|------------------------------------------------------------|
|------------------------------------------------------------|
|------------------------------------------------------------|
|------------------------------------------------------------|
|-------<7-8>----------<10-11>---------<7-8>---7--10--8--11--|x9
|-0000-----------0000------------0000----------0-------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and opening with sublime text, the text file preserve the same formatting as in your website:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://metaltabs.com/tab/4086/index.html");

$dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
// load the html into the object
$dom->loadHTML($html);
//preserve white space
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$pre= $dom->getElementsByTagName('pre');

$file = fopen('text.txt', 'w');
fwrite($file, $pre->item(0)->nodeValue);
fclose($file);
```

This is assuming that you are sure that there is only one pre tag in your page, otherwise you have to loop through the $pre variable